# How to make a Delphi Intraweb IWFrames work with IWTemplateProcessorHTML?

Tags: delphi, intraweb

I'm using Delphi 11.3 with IW15.

I have multiple iwframes, using them as a body of my page beside a header and a footer. everything is working great until I decided to use `IWTemplateProcessorHTML`.

[image]

My problem is that each iwframe has a `IWFrameRegion` which cannot be renamed for some reasons (I don't know why), although I tried to rename it various ways however it's not renamable! for that it's impossible to apply a template for each iwframe because it will have the same file name *IWFrameRegion.html* therefor it will work only for one iwframe only!

Another try was by adding another `IWRegion` and then easily rename it after that applying the `IWTemplateProcessorHTML` on it but in the end, it renders nothing! (empty page).

hence, this is how I call the iwframe to display it inside the body region:

```
   if frm1 = nil then
     begin
       frm1 := TIWFrame2.Create(self);
       frm1.Parent := IWRegion1;
       frm1.Visible := true;
    end;
```

So how to solve this issue? is my approach wrong? or there is another way to apply `IWTemplateProcessorHTML` to an iwframe? or best if maybe there is a way to rename `IWFrameRegion` ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I Found that I have to add the html file needed to custom the style in that section of the `IWTemplateProcessorHTML` marked in the image of the Object Inspector. Then hook it to `IWFrameRegion` -> [layoutMgr] and it will work!!